# How to trigger python file through html Button - Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am quite new to programming and I need your kind support.
I am trying to build a simple WebApp with flask webforms and I'd like it to work like this:

- Insert data
- Press Button
- Trigger another python script and use the input
  (As for what the .py script does, for now it is ok just to `print(info)`)

  ```
     @app.route("/form", methods=["POST"])
     def form():`
       tenant=request.form.get("t_tenant")
       VRF=request.form.get("t_vrf")
       BD=request.form.get("t_bd")
       Subnet=request.form.get("t_subnet")
       App=request.form.get("t_app")
       global info
       info=f"Tenant={tenant},\nVRF={VRF},\nBD={BD},\nSubnet={Subnet},\n, App={App}"
       file = open(r'exec.py', 'r').read()
       return render_template("forms.html", title=title, info=info)
  ```

Needless to say, it doesn't work as the "exec.py" doesn't see the "info" variable
Both .py scripts are in the same directory and the forms.html is in templates dir
Any advice are more than welcome

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have to run the `exec.py`file. Instead, you can `import` all functions from it and run the functions required.  For instance, `import exec as ex` and then run the unction required as `ex.the_function_required`. What do you want to do with `file = open(r'exec.py','r')`?

Comment: Hi, I see your point but I want two files to try not to get messy. I did the other way around, I imported the function `form()` in exec.py to use the variables. What /How does `ex.the_function_required` work? `file = open(r'exec.py','r')` trying to open and parse the file,

Answer (score 0):

I have to write it here as answer as it is long;

let's say you have the following 'parse_file' function in your exec.py:

```
def parse_file():
     print("running parse_file from exec.py")
```

Now import that exec.py file and use in form as `ex.parse_file()` the function. Instead of directly running the file, you can use the functions in this file. These functions may be some other Flask apps that may open other html files, etc.

```
 import exec as ex

@app.route("/form", methods=["POST"])

    def form():`
        tenant=request.form.get("t_tenant")
        VRF=request.form.get("t_vrf")
        BD=request.form.get("t_bd")
        Subnet=request.form.get("t_subnet")
        App=request.form.get("t_app")
        global info
        info=f"Tenant={tenant},\nVRF={VRF},\nBD={BD},\nSubnet={Subnet},\n, App={App}"
        ex.parse_file() # do what ever you want to do with the functions in exec            
        # file = open(r'exec.py', 'r').read()
        return render_template("forms.html", title=title, info=info)
```